# Move a to-do list to other card?

Tags: trello, tasks

Is it possible to move a to-do list from one card to another?

It seems difficult even to copy/paste the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Copying, cloning, and templating checklists](https://trello.com/card/copy-clone-template-boards-lists-cards-and-checklists/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c/961) is our top feature request on https://trello.com/dev.

Comment: The first ink here leads to a blank (dead?) page. The second link doesn't mention the topic. This is why link only answers are terrible.

Answer (score 2):

This feature has been added.

From the card menu select 'Copy'
It then allows you to select what items from the card to keep. If you would only like the checklist to stay, uncheck all the boxes besides checklist.

A new card will be created with your desired checklist.

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP was asking `Is it possible to move a todo-list from one card to another?` I think this might be helpful to some people - http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/35459/how-do-i-copy-a-checklist-from-one-card-to-another/35465#35465