# How do I copy a checklist from one card to another

Tags: trello

How do I copy or clone a checklist from one card to another in Trello?

Answer (score 52):

When you click add checklist there is now an option to copy checklists from other cards which are available in a dropdown.

[image]

Comment: This is to copy and it works. Another question is: there is a way to move a checklist to another card?

Comment: Copy then delete?

Comment: Yes, have to copy then delete. There seems to be no way to automatically 'move' or to 'cut and paste'.

Comment: Super cool! Not super intuitiv but if you know it it's cool! :)

Answer (score -1):

How do I copy or clone a checklist from one card to another in Trello?
I don't see this option on the Trello app for an iPhone. It works just like this on my laptop. Am I overlooking something on my phone to be able to copy a checklist?